# Indexing and Searching Lucene Index

Tags: java, lucene

I've been working with Lucene trying to builder an index file and search file that connects to my database, indexes some rows, and then searches through them.

Both of my files successfully compile but no search results are returned. The indexer connects to the database and gets the data out correctly, but I don't know if its saved to the index correctly, or if my problem is with the search file.

These files have been taken from the Lucene demo and amended to look at a database rather than .txt files.

Indexer:

```
package org.apache.lucene.demo;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.LongField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;


public class IndexFilesDB {

  private IndexFilesDB() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String usage = "java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles"
                 + " [-index INDEX_PATH] [-docs DOCS_PATH] [-update]\n\n"
                 + "This indexes the documents in DOCS_PATH, creating a Lucene index"
                 + "in INDEX_PATH that can be searched with SearchFiles";
    String indexPath = "index";
    String docsPath = null;
    String query = null;
    String connection = null;
    boolean create = true;
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++) {
      if ("-index".equals(args[i])) {
        indexPath = args[i+1];
        i++;
      } else if ("-update".equals(args[i])) {
        create = false;
        i++;
      } else if ("-q".equals(args[i])) {
        query = args[i+1];
        i++;
      } else if ("-c".equals(args[i])) {
        connection = args[i+1];
        i++;
      }
    }

    if (query == null) {
      System.err.println("Usage: " + usage);
      System.exit(1);
    }

    if (connection == null) {
      System.err.println("Usage: " + usage);
      System.exit(1);
    }


    /*final File docDir = new File(docsPath);
    if (!docDir.exists() || !docDir.canRead()) {
      System.out.println("Document directory '" +docDir.getAbsolutePath()+ "' does not exist or is not readable, please check the path");
      System.exit(1);
    }*/

    Date start = new Date();
    try {
      System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + indexPath + "'...");

      Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexPath));
      // :Post-Release-Update-Version.LUCENE_XY:
      Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47);
      IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_47, analyzer);

      if (create) {
        // Create a new index in the directory, removing any
        // previously indexed documents:
        iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
      } else {
        // Add new documents to an existing index:
        iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
      }

      // Optional: for better indexing performance, if you
      // are indexing many documents, increase the RAM
      // buffer.  But if you do this, increase the max heap
      // size to the JVM (eg add -Xmx512m or -Xmx1g):
      //
      // iwc.setRAMBufferSizeMB(256.0);

      IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
      indexDocs(writer, query, connection);

      // NOTE: if you want to maximize search performance,
      // you can optionally call forceMerge here.  This can be
      // a terribly costly operation, so generally it's only
      // worth it when your index is relatively static (ie
      // you're done adding documents to it):
      //
      // writer.forceMerge(1);

      writer.close();

      Date end = new Date();
      System.out.println(end.getTime() - start.getTime() + " total milliseconds");

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(" caught a " + e.getClass() +
       "\n with message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }


  public static void indexDocs(IndexWriter writer, String query, String connection) {
    try {
        //System.out.println("Query: " + query);
        //System.out.println("Connection: " + connection);
        Connection connect = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          // Setup the connection with the DB
          connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XXXXXX.com/mydata?"
                  + "user=username&password=password");

          // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
          statement = connect.createStatement();
          // Result set get the result of the SQL query
          resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from lists");

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            String listid = resultSet.getString("list_id");
            String listtitle = resultSet.getString("name");

            Document doc = new Document();

            doc.add(new StringField("listid", listid, Field.Store.YES));
            doc.add(new StringField("title", listtitle, Field.Store.YES));

            //System.out.println("listid: " + listid);
            //System.out.println("name: " + name);

            if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE) {
            // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be there):
            System.out.println("adding " + listtitle);
            writer.addDocument(doc);

            }


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

  }
}
```

Searcher:

```
package org.apache.lucene.demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

/** Simple command-line based search demo. */
public class SearchFilesDB {

  private SearchFilesDB() {}

  /** Simple command-line based search demo. */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String usage =
      "Usage:\tjava org.apache.lucene.demo.SearchFiles [-index dir] [-field f] [-repeat n] [-queries file] [-query string] [-raw] [-paging hitsPerPage]\n\nSee http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/demo/ for details.";
    if (args.length > 0 && ("-h".equals(args[0]) || "-help".equals(args[0]))) {
      System.out.println(usage);
      System.exit(0);
    }

    String index = "index";
    String field = "contents";
    String queries = null;
    int repeat = 0;
    boolean raw = false;
    String queryString = null;
    int hitsPerPage = 10;

    for(int i = 0;i < args.length;i++) {
      if ("-index".equals(args[i])) {
        index = args[i+1];
        i++;
      } else if ("-field".equals(args[i])) {
        field = args[i+1];
        i++;
      } else if ("-queries".equals(args[i])) {
        queries = args[i+1];
        i++;
      } else if ("-query".equals(args[i])) {
        queryString = args[i+1];
        i++;
      } else if ("-repeat".equals(args[i])) {
        repeat = Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]);
        i++;
      } else if ("-raw".equals(args[i])) {
        raw = true;
      } else if ("-paging".equals(args[i])) {
        hitsPerPage = Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]);
        if (hitsPerPage <= 0) {
          System.err.println("There must be at least 1 hit per page.");
          System.exit(1);
        }
        i++;
      }
    }

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(index)));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    // :Post-Release-Update-Version.LUCENE_XY:
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47);

    BufferedReader in = null;
    if (queries != null) {
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(queries), "UTF-8"));
    } else {
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"));
    }
    // :Post-Release-Update-Version.LUCENE_XY:
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_47, field, analyzer);
    while (true) {
      if (queries == null && queryString == null) {                        // prompt the user
        System.out.println("Enter query: ");
      }

      String line = queryString != null ? queryString : in.readLine();

      if (line == null || line.length() == -1) {
        break;
      }

      line = line.trim();
      if (line.length() == 0) {
        break;
      }

      Query query = parser.parse(line);
      System.out.println("Searching for: " + query.toString(field));

      if (repeat > 0) {                           // repeat & time as benchmark
        Date start = new Date();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
          searcher.search(query, null, 100);
        }
        Date end = new Date();
        System.out.println("Time: "+(end.getTime()-start.getTime())+"ms");
      }

      doPagingSearch(in, searcher, query, hitsPerPage, raw, queries == null && queryString == null);

      if (queryString != null) {
        break;
      }
    }
    reader.close();
  }

  public static void doPagingSearch(BufferedReader in, IndexSearcher searcher, Query query, 
                                     int hitsPerPage, boolean raw, boolean interactive) throws IOException {

    // Collect enough docs to show 5 pages
    TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 5 * hitsPerPage);
    ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;

    int numTotalHits = results.totalHits;
    System.out.println(numTotalHits + " total matching documents");

    int start = 0;
    int end = Math.min(numTotalHits, hitsPerPage);

    while (true) {
      if (end > hits.length) {
        System.out.println("Only results 1 - " + hits.length +" of " + numTotalHits + " total matching documents collected.");
        System.out.println("Collect more (y/n) ?");
        String line = in.readLine();
        if (line.length() == 0 || line.charAt(0) == 'n') {
          break;
        }

        hits = searcher.search(query, numTotalHits).scoreDocs;
      }

      end = Math.min(hits.length, start + hitsPerPage);

      for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (raw) {                              // output raw format
          System.out.println("doc="+hits[i].doc+" score="+hits[i].score);
          continue;
        }

        Document doc = searcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
        String path = doc.get("listid");
        System.out.println("here:" + path);
        if (path != null) {
          System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + path);
          String title = doc.get("title");
          if (title != null) {
            System.out.println("   Title: " + doc.get("title"));
          }
        } else {
          System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + "No path for this document");
        }

      }

      if (!interactive || end == 0) {
        break;
      }

      if (numTotalHits >= end) {
        boolean quit = false;
        while (true) {
          System.out.print("Press ");
          if (start - hitsPerPage >= 0) {
            System.out.print("(p)revious page, ");  
          }
          if (start + hitsPerPage < numTotalHits) {
            System.out.print("(n)ext page, ");
          }
          System.out.println("(q)uit or enter number to jump to a page.");

          String line = in.readLine();
          if (line.length() == 0 || line.charAt(0)=='q') {
            quit = true;
            break;
          }
          if (line.charAt(0) == 'p') {
            start = Math.max(0, start - hitsPerPage);
            break;
          } else if (line.charAt(0) == 'n') {
            if (start + hitsPerPage < numTotalHits) {
              start+=hitsPerPage;
            }
            break;
          } else {
            int page = Integer.parseInt(line);
            if ((page - 1) * hitsPerPage < numTotalHits) {
              start = (page - 1) * hitsPerPage;
              break;
            } else {
              System.out.println("No such page");
            }
          }
        }
        if (quit) break;
        end = Math.min(numTotalHits, start + hitsPerPage);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone is able to point me in the right direction with where I'm going wrong it would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
I've used Luke to take a look in the index as suggested by AKS and I can see the terms in the index.

[image]

I guess this must be a problem with the search file then?

Comment: Just in case you want to check whether the data has been indexed or not, you can use LukeAll https://code.google.com/p/luke/downloads/detail?name=lukeall-3.5.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out!

In the indexer file I was indexing fields 'listid' and 'title':

```
doc.add(new StringField("listid", listid, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new StringField("title", listtitle, Field.Store.YES));
```

but in the searcher file it was set at the very top of the file to look for the field 'contents':

```
String field = "contents";
```

If anyone else comes up against a similar problem I would suggest using LukeAll as AKS suggested to me. I had to use a lower version of Lucene to get it to work but it definitely helped!